# Debug the LLVM installed in my machine to know about the conversion from IR to Machine code

Tags: debugging, assembly, llvm, llvm-ir

I wanted to learn how LLVM translate IR into machine code of specific target. How the mapping is done?

I wanted to go into debug mode and debug any c++ files of LLVM. But I don't know whether it is possible or not ? I just wanted to learn IR to machine conversion with the help of code LLVM is using ?

Comment: Sure you can, you can debug any C++ program when you have the source code, and LLVM is open source.  However, I don't think this will necessarily be a helpful way to try to understand it, given the sheer size and complexity of LLVM.  You'll probably do better to start by learning basic theory of compiler design.